# Magento 2.4.4 and PHP 8 "A technical problem with the server created an error." When open any customer

Tags: customer, error, magento2.4.4

how to fix and how debug the below error. I am getting this issue when I opened any customer it's showing not continuously sometimes it happens.

> A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to
> continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again
> later.

I have tried already to change the user password, check the index.php for any echo code, tried also to upgrade, compile, deploy, reindex, and clean the cache, but nothing, I still get this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message **`"A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later"`** in Magento 2 can occur for a variety of reasons. Some possible causes include:

1. Server-side issues: This error can occur if there is a problem with
   the server, such as a lack of resources, a configuration issue, or a
   software bug.
2. Database connectivity issues: If there is a problem connecting to
   the database, this error can occur.
3. Incorrect file permissions: If the file permissions on the server
   are set incorrectly, Magento may not be able to access the necessary
   files and this error will occur.
4. Caching issues: If there is an issue with caching, such as outdated
   cache files or a problem with the caching configuration, this error
   can occur.
5. Extension conflicts: If there is a conflict between Magento
   extensions, this error can occur.
6. Custom code conflicts: If there is a conflict with custom code, this
   error can occur.
7. Server overload: High traffic can overload the server and cause this
   error.

It is best to check the server logs, database logs, and Magento logs to get more insights on the issue and determine the exact cause of the problem, then take the necessary steps to resolve it. Also, if you have recently made any changes to the server, site or extension, you can try to revert those changes, that might help you resolve the problem.

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: thanks for the comment. i will check

Comment: Okay, If Answer is helpful please accept that answer to other community helpful.

Comment: @Devidas My answer is helpful? If yes, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

**A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.** this error coming in the below files

```
lib/web/mage/backend/bootstrap.js
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/backend/bootstrap.js
```

For me when the ajax request POST method failed that time I am getting a technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.
Something went wrong.
If i Add New Record Then Error Accure But Data insert And Updated..